# How to mark a method as deprecated with swagger_auto_schema?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

I'm using `swagger-auto-schema` to document my endpoints API using `django-rest-framework`, `swagger`, and `drf-yasg`. Is there a way to mark the API endpoints in the documentation as deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

You should set `deprecated=True` parameter on the **swagger_auto_schema** decorator.

Example:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @swagger_auto_schema(deprecated=True)
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```